# Revolut OpenBanking API Authentication and Authorization

Tags: open-banking, psd2

I am trying to use [Revolut Open Banking API](https://revolut-engineering.github.io/oba/#getting-started) and I can't figure out how the authorization and authentication flow works.

What is the dynamic client registration? Should I register the application every single time I start my application? 
What about the certificates - how does it work?

Does anyone have sample applications to check?

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic client registration you can create client ID for your application using ASPSP's (Revolut's) API. It is described here: https://openbanking.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DZ/pages/937066600/Dynamic+Client+Registration+-+v3.1

With some ASPSPs you can also do this through their dev portals. Obvious advantage of dynamic client registration (compared to dev portals) is in possibility to automate client registration through out multiple ASPSPs.

In my company's blog there is an [article about dynamic client registration with step-by-step guide and code snippets in Python helping to complete the registration](https://enablebanking.com/blog/2020/02/05/dynamic-client-registration/).

You only need to register your application once, but you can change its properties whenever you want.